# Как отправить капчу на проверку если нет кнопки "Отправить"?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не могу понять как отправить капчу на проверку? Где-то читал что можно как-то через js, но не знаю как , может кто-то поможет.  У большинства капч , есть кнопка "Отправить" или "Подтвердить", после чего капча проверяется, но в моем случае такого нет, и мне нужно узнать как отправить капчу на проверку, без кнопки.

[image: 1]